# Is there a standard Linux library for "lock files"?

Tags: linux, file, synchronization, locking

Suppose I have a folder and I want only one instance of my application working on it at a time. I can only synchronize via the filesystem itself. Often times this is a accomplished with something like a `.lock_file` where if that's present I know another instance is currently using it. Are there any standard libraries that handle this sort of thing?

Comment: Which OS and language/framework? If you add these as tags you'll get more views and hopefully an answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using C/C++, see fclnt or flock :
[Locking files in linux with c/c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2057784/locking-files-in-linux-with-c-c)

If you are using java, see [FileChannel lock method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/channels/FileChannel.html)
and 
[How can I lock a file using java (if possible)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/128038/how-can-i-lock-a-file-using-java-if-possible)

You also can check for the existence of the `.lock_file` opening it with
`open(pathname, O_CREAT | O_EXCL, 0644)`, 
see [open man page](http://linux.die.net/man/2/open), it creates and opens the file and returns EEXIST if pathname exists.

In java, calling to [File method createNewFile()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#createNewFile%28%29) can be use to create atomically the `.lock_file`