# Detect a file is closed

Tags: linux, file

Is there a simple way to detect when a file for writing is closed?  I have a process that kicks out a new file every 5 seconds.  I can not change the code for that process.  I am writing another process to analyze the contents of each file immediately when it is created.  Is there a simple way to watch a certain directory to see when a file is no longer opened for writing?  I'm hoping for some sort of Linux command.

Comment: What language? What context is each process called?

Comment: In order to have extra time to process the file, consider creating a file system in memory - that ought to speed things up.

Comment: Any language.  I was hoping for something in bash, but anything will do.  The process is a command-line utility that is executed directly by the user and runs for several hours.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can put something on top of strace to raise your events.

try:

```
strace ls 2>&1 | grep "close\|open"
```

Using inotify is also a good idea, but will probably require more coding to get what you need.

Comment: +1 sounds like a great idea.  However, the pipe doesn't seem to work.  I think strace is running on "command | grep fclose" instead of just "command".  Any hints?

Comment: oops, I updated the answer to have a working example :). strace prints to stderr by default.

Comment: that seems to have worked.  It's very cool that I can also see which shared libraries are used by the executable.  Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

If you know there is some particular text (line) in the file that indicates completion of writing you could easily watch for that using commands like `grep`

Also, you can use `fuser` command to find out if a file is in use.

Answer (score 2):

As you are using linux as your platform you might want to have a look at the inotify syscalls. When monitoring the directory were the output files are written you will get open/close events for the files created there.

If you want to integrate this into a shell script have a look at inotifywait which is part of the inotify-tools.

Answer (score 1):

You could [lock the contents of your file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/575328/fcntl-lockf-which-is-better-to-use-for-file-locking/575349#575349) until you're done using it.

Comment: Voluntary locking is advisable.

Answer (score 1):

If you know the process ID of the process that is writing the files, you can watch `/proc/<pid>/fd/` to see which files it has open.