# c++ Make sure hardware gets accessed only by one program

Tags: c++, linux, hardware

I am currently working with a raspberry pi.

I have written a simple library to control a 7 segment display and it works fine. I also made several programs that use the library.

I need to make sure that at any time only one program is trying to control the [gpio](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General-purpose_input/output)'s. My first idea was to create a lock on a specific file.
**How good practice is this and what's the best way to completely realize that**?

*(To clear this up: I do not neccesarrily want to block all programms from using the gpio's. It would be enough if only one program using my library could acces the gpio's)*

Comment: I think that making files to signal that something is in use at the moment is common on Linux.

Comment: That's true. I have seen this many times. I'm still not entirly sure if this the best practise in this case...

Comment: How do you access the gpio?

Comment: Using the [WiringPi API](http://wiringpi.com/)

Comment: If you decide to go with file locking, here is a good discussion:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/575328/fcntl-lockf-which-is-better-to-use-for-file-locking

Comment: So is it "good" practise?